# SELECT Distinct and IIF not giving expected results

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I need some assistance with a SQL query in Access as I'm a novice.

I have a table `tbl_FC_Data` with rows of data that contain a forecast labeled by a *forecast date* of *quantity* by *part number* by *future month* for a *company*.  So a single forecast for a *company* will contain a row for each *future month* for each *part number*.  Here is sample data:

```
Part_Number  Company_Code  Qty  Data_Month  Date_of_FC
9D0094-2      EAIL1         5   08/01/20    06/01/20
9D0094-2      EAIL1         7   09/01/20    06/01/20
9D0094-2      EAIL1         8   10/01/20    06/01/20
9D0166-24     EAIL1         2   08/01/20    06/01/20
9D0197-1      EAIL1         2   08/01/20    06/01/20
9D0094-2      EAIL1         6   08/01/20    07/01/20
9D0094-5      EAIL1         8   08/01/20    07/01/20
9D0166-10     EAIL1         9   08/01/20    07/01/20
9D0166-24     EAIL1         2   08/01/20    07/01/20
9D0094-2      EAIL1         3   08/01/20    07/01/20
9D0094-4      EAIL1         4   08/01/20    07/01/20
```

My goal is to compare two forecasts for company to determine whether a part number is contained in both or just the first or just the second forecast. Here is the sample result:

```
Part_Number  Company_Code   First_Date_Match  Second_Date_Match
9D0094-2       EAIL1               Y            Y
9D0094-4       EAIL1               N            Y
9D0094-5       EAIL1               N            Y           
9D0166-10      EAIL1               N            Y
9D0166-24      EAIL1               N            Y
9D0197-1       EAIL1               Y            N
```

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried several SQL variations including `GROUP BY` `Part_Number`.  Below is my latest try using `SELECT DISTINCT`.  When a `Part_Number` appears in both `Date_of_FC` I **do not** get a `First_Date_Match` of `Y` and a `Second_Date_Match` of `Y`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FC_Data.Part_Number, IIf([tbl_FC_Data]![Date_of_FC]=#7/1/2020#,"Y","N") AS 
First_Date_Match, IIf([tbl_FC_Data]![Date_of_FC]=#6/1/2020#,"Y","N") AS Second_Date_Match
    FROM tbl_FC_Data
    WHERE (((tbl_FC_Data.Company_Code)="EAIL1") AND ((tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC)=#7/1/2020#)) OR 
        (((tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC)=#6/1/2020#))
    ORDER BY tbl_FC_Data.Part_Number;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbl_FC_Data.Part_Number,
    IIf(MAX([tbl_FC_Data]![Date_of_FC]) = #7/1/2020#,"Y","N") AS First_Date_Match,
    IIf(MIN([tbl_FC_Data]![Date_of_FC]) = #6/1/2020#,"Y","N") AS Second_Date_Match
FROM tbl_FC_Data
WHERE tbl_FC_Data.Company_Code = "EAIL1"
    AND tbl_FC_Data.Date_of_FC IN (#7/1/2020#, #6/1/2020#)
GROUP BY tbl_FC_Data.Part_Number
ORDER BY tbl_FC_Data.Part_Number;
```